# GET input method isn't logging data into Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, get, eloquent

Trying to create a simple input method. My DB table (comments) contains an increment "id", varchar(30) "name", and text "comments".

A URL such as **app.local/comments?name=John&comments=test** is how I would like to input data into my application.

My route entry:

```
Route::get('comments', 'CommentsController@index');
```

My Comments Controller:

```
<?php

class CommentsController extends \BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $comments = Input::get('comments');
    }
}
```

My Comments Model:

```
<?php

class Comments extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'comments';

}
```

After several variations and no errors I can not get data into my table. Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you do not persist data, you need to instantiate a new model, then `save` it:

```
$comment = new Comments;
$comment->name = Input::get('name');
$comment->comments = Input::get('comments');
$comment->save();
```

I recommend you to learn more about [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Comment: Thank you Razor. I will RTFM next time! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also, note that you can do it like Razor said even if it isn't set as $fillable in your model.

In order to use,

```
Comments::create(array(
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
    'comments' => Input::get('comments')
));
```

you need to make sure in your model, the $fillable array has `name` and `comments` in it.